# winform how to avoid two panel docking to be overlapped

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Here is the picture to show the left panel is docked to left while the main panel is docked to Fill, but the left panel is overlapping the main panel

[image]

Any one know how to solve this problem?

Comment: in the main menu of visual studio choose View / Other Windows / Document Outline. This will bring up a very very slow list of objects, where you can change the z-order of the objects. Just move panels until the desired result. Attention though, when this view is opened your visual studio will be very very very very slow until you close it and restart visual studio. Also beware that if the form is inherited from another form this might not work since visual inheritance is very poor supported in "unvisual" studio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure there are on same level, play a little bit with:

```
Right Click on the control -> Send to Back or Bring to Front
```

options.

To give a bit more explanation:

If one of your panel is Dock to Left and the other to Bottom, but those are not on same level (Left panel is above Bottom one) Left panel will never force Bottom panel to move, as Bottom panel can use whole space, as on it's level there is nothing docked to Left it that makes sense.

Situation change if those two panels are on same level, then they respect each others docking.

In your scenario, you want to push your left hand side panel to back, so it is on same level with Main panel, and then act same way with the Bottom one, as needed.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

The order in which the panels are created is causing this.
You can change this order with the document outline.
Set one panel higher in the list than the other, play with it until you get the desired result. Than close this window. In my case I also have to restart visual studio now since this view somehow makes visual studio very slow.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have done the same thing but for me the two panels are not overlapping.

Let me tell you the steps I followed.

I took one panel from toolbox. Then made a copy of same panel by click and drag. I then changed their color two red and yellow respectively to differentiate between them. Then for red panel i set dock to left and for yellow panel I set dock to fill. Below is the screenshot for the same.

[image: First case] 
First case

[image: Second Case]
Second Case

[image: Third Case]
Third Case

Comment: Do you know that it matters in what order those panel has been added? And what was a focused control when next panels have been added as well? That would work only in some routine of adding the controls.

Comment: I just noticed, your yellow and green panels are also under the red one, so it's not really working for you either.

Comment: Its working. Since the red panel has already occupied the left part of window, the other panel will start from the point where the first ends.